# does semaphore preserve wait order

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have multi-threaded (say 3 threads) application, each one has different priority.

suppose threads t1, t2, t3 have priorities p1, p2, p3 where **p2 > p3**
they're competing to get a semaphore and **t3 calls sem_wait() before t2** does.

suppose that thread one succeeds in getting the semaphore. after unlocking it which thread executes first t2 or t3.

NB: I know that with mutexes' the behavior is undefined.

Comment: No, it does not give that guarantee.

Comment: an accurate answer may be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_post.html)